# Convergence of a series and and an application of bounded linear operator operator

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis

My question is more of a sanity check, for two ideas

If I have a series $\sum_{i=1} ^{\infty} a_i A(e_i) = 0$ where $A$ is a bounded linear operator $A\colon H \rightarrow H$ and $\{e_i \}$ are the orthonormal basis of $H$ and $a_i \geq 0$ for all $i$. Then we cannot say that $\sum_{i=1} ^{\infty} a_i A(e_i) = 0$  implies that $a_i A(e_i) = 0$ for all $i$, is that correct? My reasoning is calculus motivated for example we can have an alternating type of series were no term is zero but when we add them up we get zero.

However if we have an extra condition on $A$ say it is positive in the sense of bounded linear operators $\langle x,Ax \rangle > 0$, then $\sum_{i=1} ^{\infty} a_i A(e_i) = 0$ would imply that $a_i A(e_i) = 0$ for all $i$. My reasoning is that

$$0=\sum_{i=1} ^{\infty} a_i A(e_i) = \sum_{i=1} ^{\infty} a_i \sum_{j=1} ^\infty\langle A(e_i), e_j \rangle e_j= \sum_{i,j}a_i \langle A(e_i), e_j \rangle e_j$$
So I think from there we can say that $a_i \langle A(e_i), e_j \rangle e_j=0$ which itself would imply that $a_i= 0$ or $\langle A(e_i), e_j \rangle=0$. Is my reasoning sound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, consider $T: l^2 \to l^2, (x_n)_n \mapsto (0, x_1 - x_2, 0, \cdots)$. This operator is linear and bounded. Choose $a_i = 1$ for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$. Let $e_n$ be the standard ONB in $l^2$.
Then $\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_iT(e_i) = T(e_1) + T(e_2) = (0,1,0, \cdots) + (0, -1, 0, \cdots) = 0$, but $a_1T(e_1) = (0,1,0, \cdots) \neq 0$. 

If you require the operator to be positive your argument is fine.